# List of all packages installed using Homebrew

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source

Is it possible to and how do I get a list of all the packages installed on my Mac using Homebrew? I am not interested in packages installed outside of Homebrew.

Answer (score 1159, accepted):

## `brew list` and `brew list --cask`

Running `brew list` will show a list of all your installed Homebrew packages.

In addition, `brew list --cask` will provide the items installed using [Homebrew Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask).

[image: brew list]

Comment: If you had this list in a txt file. How would you go about installing all of them? `brew install < list.txt` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Jonathan `xargs brew install < list.txt` Feel free to ask a separate question for more details or clarification.

Comment: @grgarside - love ur terminal prompt. would you be willing to share your config files for getting my prompt to look like that?

Comment: @Kaushik I've finally written a blog post about [my terminal/shell setup](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/terminal-shell-zsh-setup/)—feel free to ask any questions there.

Comment: also added the `--versions` flag at the end to get the list with the versions installed

Comment: `brew list -1` to _"Force output to be one entry per line"_ (see `man brew`). 
However, please note that if you want to re-install everything you asked from brew before, it's better to generate your list using `brew leaves --installed-on-request` (short: `brew leaves -r`) …so once you install from that list you will get only your tools incl. the dependencies that matter at that moment—v.s. using the output of `brew list` that will include _dependencies that might have become obsolete by the time you wish to re-install your tools._

Answer (score 642):

`brew leaves` shows you all top-level packages; packages that are not dependencies. This should be the most interesting if you are using the list to re-install packages.

To include *formula* descriptions, use

```
brew leaves | xargs brew desc --eval-all
```

To include *cask* descriptions, use

```
brew ls --casks | xargs brew desc --eval-all
```

Comment: Only list leaves that were manually installed: `brew leaves --installed-on-request | xargs -n1 brew desc`

Comment: `brew leaves` is missing any casks

Comment: At least since brew 3.5.10 (August 2022), `brew desc` is deprecated; `brew desc --eval-all` should be used.

Also, this allows fetching descriptions for more than one package in one call. This is quicker by a factor of roughly the number of descriptions requested. This modified `xargs` command will make use of that:
`brew leaves | xargs brew desc --eval-all`

Comment: @PabloBianchi what leaves would not have been installed on request?

Answer (score 165):

[`brew bundle`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle) may also be interesting if you are asking because you want to manage your brew installation. This includes casks, which `brew list` does not. It is aimed at having reproducible Homebrew setups.

```
# creates Brewfile in the current directory from currently-installed packages
brew bundle dump
# edit Brewfile
# install everything from the Brewfile
brew bundle
```

You can use the `--global` flag to operate on your `~/.Brewfile` and `-f/--force` to force overwriting of your existing file (for installation, this will force uninstallation of not-listed packages).

Comment: A recent dump of mine suggests that `bundle` now excludes dependencies. There are some other changes like quote style and ordering that are making it harder to understand the diff, but overall it looks like at least some libraries are missing from `Brewfile` but installed.

Comment: • My desired effect is to have the same brew based software at my disposal on machine B like I now have at machine A. But to freshly configure the individual apps there to have a save fresh start and get rid of any cruft I may accumulated over the years on machine A.

• Is "brew bundle dump" on machine A, moving ~/Brewfile to machine B and there running "brew bundle" the right command sequence for this purpose?

• After installation on the new machine B will brew there install the correct architecture (i.e. Apple Silicon instead of Intel x64) and install all necessary dependencies?

Comment: You can check `brew bundle --help` for specifics and examine the Brewfile. I believe this answer is more complete and idiomatic way to do it than the accepted answer - for example, it includes taps and casks. It is architecture-independent and will install dependencies. If you want machine B to also uninstall packages which are not in the Brewfile, you'll need to provide `--cleanup` or do a separate `brew bundle cleanup`.

Comment: That's probably the best option I have seen. It also works with optional software `mas-cli` that manages App Store installations, so you can not only save the brews and casks but also software installed through App Store! Sweet; thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 96):

Executing `brew list` command shows a simple, alphabetically  sorted list of all the installed formulae and Casks (GUI apps) into two separate sections.

[image]

However, other required formulae (dependencies) get automatically installed when installing a formulae. It is possible to view the list of all the installed packages as a nicely formatted dependency tree. To view it, execute the following command:

`brew deps --tree --installed`

An example output is as shown below:

[image]

The independently listed formulae (e.g. `bash`, `brotli`, `ca-certificates` etc.) have no dependencies. The formulae depicted as part of a tree structure have their dependency listed at an immediate lower level in the tree (e.g. `cocoapods` requires `ruby` which in tern requires `libyaml` to be installed). The formulae listed at the leaf nodes in the tree structures have no further dependencies.

Dependencies visualised in a tree structure like this can help in easily getting rid of the unnecessary packages.

Comment: Great answer. I'm getting my top-level packages with: `brew deps --tree --installed --full-name | grep -v "└" | grep -e "^\w" | count`.
How to see the differences between formulae and casks

Answer (score 18):

Others have mentioned `brew leaves`, which lists things that aren't dependencies; and `brew deps --tree --installed` which lists the dependency tree for all installed packages.

I find the most useful output of any answers yet is the combination of these.

```sh
brew deps --tree $(brew leaves)
```

This will list a tree of your brew install.

Edit: This doesn't include packages that were installed as build dependencies (nor other optional dependencies). It also doesn't include casks.

Comment: doesn't show cask packages. `brew bundle dump` seems better https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256269/48582

Answer (score 15):

You may use `brew list | grep 'package-name'` or  if are looking for specific package. 
`brew list 'package-name'` also works and provides additional information.

Answer (score 9):

To see brew packages :

```
brew list
```

To see cask packages :

```
brew list --cask
```

To see upgradable brew packages :

```
brew outdated
```

To see upgradable cask packages

```
brew outdated --cask
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/eguven/23d8c9fc78856bd20f65f8bcf03e691b) to list all installed packages and sort them by their size.

```bsh
brew list --formula | \
    xargs -n1 -P8 -I {} \
    sh -c "
        brew info {} | \
        egrep '[0-9]* files, ' | \
        sed 's/^.*[0-9]* files, \(.*\)).*$/{} \1/'
    " | \
    sort -h -r -k2 - | \
    column -t
```

Comment: Cool but it seems to hammer my CPU and disk. I wonder when it will finish.

Comment: Yes, getting the size requires an info query for each package. It takes around a minute for 120 packages.

Answer (score 5):

**Short and crisp**

```
brew list --versions


MACBOOK:/ world.peace$ brew list --version
apache-spark 3.2.1
openjdk 18
openjdk@11 11.0.14.1
sbt 1.6.2
scala 2.13.8
tree 2.0.2
```

Similarly, you can use:

```
brew list --cask
```

Answer (score 3):

This commands lists manually installed packages, cask or not, with versions:

```bash
cat \
    <(brew leaves --installed-on-request) \
    <(brew list --cask -1) |
brew ls --versions | sort | uniq
```

Also to see which packages are installed by both cask and not cask:

```bash
cat \
    <(brew leaves --installed-on-request) \
    <(brew list --cask -1) |
sort | uniq
```

Comment: I got a syntax error running this in bash shell.

Comment: @Jasha I have added bash version

Answer (score -1):

If you want to migrate the packages to another MacBook it's nice to know the different lists for formulae and casks:

**List all top level installed packages (without casks)**

```sh
comm -12 \
<(brew deps --tree --installed --full-name | grep -v "└" | grep -e "^\w" | sort) \
<(brew ls --full-name --formula | sort)
```

**List all top level installed casks (without packages)**

```sh
comm -12 \
<(brew deps --tree --installed --full-name | grep -v "└" | grep -e "^\w" | sort) \
<(brew ls --full-name --cask | sort)
```

Alternatively you can use `sort` and `uniq`:

```sh
sort \
<(brew deps --tree --installed --full-name | grep -v "└" | grep -e "^\w" | sort) \
<(brew ls --full-name --cask | sort) \
| uniq -d
```

Comment: Isn‘t this simplified by `brew bundle dump`/`brew bundle install`?