# Display the app location of every cask

Tags: homebrew

I know how to use [`brew cask list`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101092/154794) to display every installed cask. However, this only provides me with the name of each cask:

```
1password
1password-cli
font-fira-code
font-ubuntu
geekbench
visual-studio-code
```

However, I would like to know where each cask's main artifact is located without running `brew cask info` on each one. Is it possible to get a list of casks while also showing their main artifact's path? For example:

```
1password             ~/Applications/1Password 7.app
1password-cli         /usr/local/bin/op
font-fira-code        ~/Library/Fonts/FiraCode-Regular.otf
font-ubuntu           ~/Library/Fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf
geekbench             ~/Applications/Geekbench 4.app
visual-studio-code    ~/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ for f in `brew cask list`; do brew cask info $f | grep -e [^B]\)$ | sed -e s/^/"$f":/g; done
emacs:Emacs.app (App)
emacs:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -> emacs (Binary)
emacs:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/ebrowse (Binary)
emacs:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient (Binary)
emacs:/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/etags (Binary)
macvim:macvim: 8.1.950,155 (auto_updates)
macvim:MacVim.app (App)
macvim:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -> gview (Binary)
macvim:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -> gvim (Binary)
macvim:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -> gvimdiff (Binary)
macvim:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -> mview (Binary)
macvim:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -> mvimdiff (Binary)
macvim:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -> view (Binary)
macvim:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -> vim (Binary)
macvim:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -> vimdiff (Binary)
macvim:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/mvim -> mvim (Binary)
minikube:minikube-darwin-amd64 -> minikube (Binary)
osxfuse:osxfuse: 3.8.3 (auto_updates)
osxfuse:Extras/FUSE for macOS 3.8.3.pkg (Pkg)
virtualbox:VirtualBox.pkg (Pkg)
wireshark:Wireshark 3.0.1 Intel 64.pkg (Pkg)
xmind:XMind.app (App)
```